# how to detect a browser is maxlength feature enable

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser

I thought I could detect by doing like this but it was not.

```js
var input = $("#d_textarea");
var str = "123456789012";
input.val(str);
var maxlengthEnable = (input.val() != str);
console.log(maxlengthEnable);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="d_textarea" maxlength=10></textarea>
```

is there any way to detect a browser enable maxlegnth feature?

Comment: i guess if(input.attr("maxLength")) { ... } is what you want..?

Comment: `maxlength` is supported by all browsers, new and old. So there's no need to check for this specific attribute. If you set this attribute it will work.

Comment: @Gil Under IE9, not supported

Comment: @dajeongda if you already know it, why the tests?

Comment: @DemoUser It seems elements can have all attr regardless of working exactly or not. IE9, it is true but not working. I can type in textarea over 50 length string... anyway thanks.

Comment: @Gil try on textarea, It dones't. I see it works well on input type element, thanks but I have to use this feature on textarea...

Comment: @dajeongda You're right, only IE10 supports this, my mistake.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Knu I want to know the browser actually supports(performs) maxlength feature. It returns true $("#d_textarea")[0].maxLength when element has a maxlength attribute whether it really performs preventing typing or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below code to check that browser supports maxlength:

```
if (!("maxLength" in document.createElement("textarea"))) {
    alert('Browser doesn\'t supports maxlength');
} else {
    alert('Browser support maxlength');
}
```

**maxLength** is case sensitive here.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the existence of this option by looking at the object element.

`$("#d_textarea")[0].maxLength` holds the implementation of the `maxlength` attribute. If this value is undefined or simply doesn't exist, it means it's not supported by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for maxlength attribute, it is supported by all browsers from very start. Please check : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: try on textarea, it is not supported.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp - it says "Differences Between HTML 4.01 and HTML5. The maxlength attribute is new for the <textarea> tag in HTML5."

Answer (score 0):

On browser tick F12 aka developer mode, You can just check the property of the HTML textbox, drill down and look to properties you should see maxLength property. -1 is default, and other value is defined by you